# Python 3 comparison between two individual members of a list returning false in a search function

Tags: python, list, search, nested-loops, linear-search

I've been struggling to debug this function. The goal of the function is to search between two lists and print any common list items. I've traced and traced through this nested for loop with print statements and haven't been able to determine the issue. The loop seems to always return false on the print statement even when comparing two list items that are the same so I don't think the logic of the nested for loop is the issue.

I'm relatively new to Python so I'm sure the answer is something dumb.

```
list_one = [banana, orange, apple]
list_two = [monkey, dog, cat, apple]


def search_lists(list_one, list_two):
    match = False
    
    for items in list_one:
        for data in list_two:
            if (data == items):
                print(data)
                match = True
                print("match found")
                
    return match

search_lists(list_one, list_two)
```

Comment: do you want to return True if any one the items is matched?

Comment: The items in your list must be string type : list_one = ["banana", "orange", "apple"].For example, apple alone does not make sense

Answer (score 0):

Put '' around list items. list_one = ['banana', 'orange', 'apple'] and list_two = ['monkey', 'dog', 'cat', 'apple']

Edit: If you want to print the list of items matched from the lists then you can use list comprehension as well:

```
    def search_lists(list_one, list_two):
    x = [item for item in list_one for data in list_two if data == item]
    return x


list_one = ['banana', 'orange', 'apple']
list_two = ['monkey', 'dog', 'cat', 'apple']

print(search_lists(list_one, list_two))
```

Answer (score 0):

The initialisation of `list_one` and `list_two` is not correct.

- If u want those data to be strings use

```py
list_one = ["banana", "orange", "apple"]
```

- If u want those data to be variables, initialize them before using. E.g.

```py
banana = 0
orange = 1
apple = 2
list_one = [banana, orange, apple]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def intersection_1(lst1, lst2):
    lst3 = [value for value in lst1 if value in lst2]
    return lst3


def intersection_2(lst1, lst2):
    return list(set(lst1) & set(lst2))


def intersection_3(lst1, lst2):
    return list(set(lst1).intersection(lst2))


lst1 = ['banana', 'orange', 'apple']
lst2 = ['monkey', 'dog', 'cat', 'apple']

print(intersection_1(lst1, lst2)) # ['apple']
print(intersection_2(lst1, lst2)) # ['apple']
print(intersection_3(lst1, lst2)) # ['apple']
```